# Going from one view to another view in Spring, doesn't actually redirect - just adds the new view to the current view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

So, I have a home page that goes to index.jsp. Which is fine. On this page there's a search button and is supposed to bring you to room-list.jsp but instead it simply gets embedded in to index.jsp and I can't understand why.

I've tried returning "redirect:/room-list" but that seems to be trying to go to another controller rather than a jsp if that makes sense? I'm so stuck. Here's a screenshot of what's happening, as you can see there's 2 banners since room-list.jsp is getting added on top of index.jsp: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9clq8.jpg

Here's what's in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("in controller");

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showMessage2(@Valid SearchCmd searchCmd, Model model) {
    System.out.println("in search controller");

    return "room-list";
}
```

Web.xml
         
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you please show `index.jsp` or at least the part concerning the search button ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using:

```
RequestMethod.POST
```

Try to change it to:

```
RequestMethod.GET
```

and you will get redirect to room-list page.

This tutorial may help: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html

He's using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

To get the page first, then he uses

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

To do business stuff.

Comment: Hmmmm...changed my controller part to Get and in my jsp added method="get" to the form but seems to be still expecting Post for some reason.

Comment: So can you redirect to list-room.jsp after changing from POST to GET?

Comment: Nope. but the problem was actually a javascript problem. In my javascript it was actually changing the form to a POST. Thanks for the help!